# JS расширение. Можно ли добавить в расширение html страницу, но не popup. А просто страницу, которая будет открывается на соседней вкладке

Tags: javascript, браузер

Впринципе ничего сложного нет, что бы создать страницу и положить её в папку с проектом. Но она не прописана в manifest(я просто не знаю как это сделать, и можно ли вообще), следовательно я никак не могу передать этой странице необходимую мне информацию. она как бы в не расширения. Функции специфичные для расширения на ней просто не работают, и выдают ошибки. Хоть я и использую на ней скрипты, которые прописаны в манифесте.

Мне нужно что бы по клику по иконке расширения, открывалась новая страница с графиками, с информацией с определенной страницы. Все это у меня уже реализованно, только вот никак не могу передать информацию. Это в принципе возможно реализовать?

Comment: браузер укажите, откуда нам знать что это хром?

Comment: Браузер google chrome Версия 68.0.3440.106 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)